# Euclidean geometry problem from Euclidean and Non Euclidean Geometry: An Analytic Approach by Patrick J Ryan

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, reflection

Let $l=P+[v]$ be a line. Let $m=Q+[v]$. Show that if $|v|=1$, then $Ω_{l}Ω_{m}=τ_{w}$, where $w=2<P-Q,V^{⟂}>V^{⟂}$ and $Ω_{m}Ω_{l}=τ_{-w}$

I honestly have no idea how to start this. I know the following definitions:

For a line $l$, the reflection in $l$ is the mapping $Ω_{l}x=x-2<x-p,N>N$ where $N$ is a unit normal to $l$ and $P$ is any point of $l$.

If $v=(v_{1}, v_{2})$, then $V^{⟂}=(-v_{2}, v_{1})$

We haven't covered product of reflections nor translations so I don't know the definitions.
Literally any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: $\Omega_l\Omega_m(x)=\Omega_l(\Omega_m(x))$.

Comment: @Aretino sorry could you explain a bit more?

Comment: To apply $\Omega_l\Omega_m$ to a vector $x$ you must apply $\Omega_l$ to $\Omega_m x$. That is: a product of two transformation is nothing but their composition.

Comment: @Aretino okay i understand the product then. Do you have any advice for how i would go about solving the question? Would I do the left hand side, $Ω_{l}Ω_{m}$ and then the right hand side, $T_{-w}$ and see if they match up? I'm also not sure, is $T_{w}$ ,meant to equal $T_{-w}$?

Comment: Yes, carefully computing $\Omega_l\Omega_m$ should be enough.