# Euclidean Geometry Translations

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We haven't covered translations yet but we have problems on it so I'm reading the textbook. From what I understand the composition of two reflections is a translation? This was the explanation in the book.
[image]

I understand lines 1-3. 
My confusion comes from how did they get from 3 to 4. Thank you for your time

Comment: Why did you ask the same thing twice? See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187704/euclidean-geometry-problem-from-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometry-an-analyti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the following formulation of the scalar product of two vectors $v, w$:
$$
\langle v , w\rangle = |v| \cdot |w| \cdot \cos(\varphi)
$$
where $\varphi$ is the angle between $v$ and $w$. In your situation the vector $P-Q$ points in the same (or opposite) direction as $N$, because the line $PQ$ is perpendicular to $\mathit{m}$. Thus you either get $\cos(\varphi)=1$
$$
\langle P-Q , N\rangle N = (|P-Q|\cdot |N|) \cdot N = |P-Q| \cdot N = P-Q
$$
if $N$ and $P-Q$ point in the same direction, or $\cos(\varphi)=-1$
$$
\langle P-Q , N\rangle N = (|P-Q|\cdot |N| \cdot (-1) )\cdot N = (-1) \cdot|P-Q| \cdot N = (-1) (Q-P) = P-Q
$$
if $N$ and $P-Q$ point in opposite directions.

Comment: So I drew out the diagram and I see what you mean by they point in the same (or opposite direction) . Can I ask how $(|P−Q|⋅|N|)⋅N$ becomes $|P−Q|⋅N$?

Comment: Oh wait nevermind I get that part now. Thank so much!